# Assembler subroutine to modify a C array

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, x86-64, subroutine

I'm trying to link an assembler subroutine for sorting numbers with a C code with my friend for a group assignment and we have trouble getting it to work. The sorting algorithm (Shellsort) has been tested before as a separate program and should work.

We are using the mysort method to call the routine that modifies the array:

```
void mysort (uint32_t array[], uint32_t len);
```

We read the input numbers from a file into the array:

```
len = read(f, array, ARRAY_SIZE*4);
```

We call the sorting routine like this:

```
 mysort(array, len>>2);
```

In the end we write the array back to a file. The problem is that our output is an array containing the original numbers in the same order, instead of being sorted like they should. We pass the pointer to the array to the array through the RCX register, as this is how function parameters are passed in Intel-64. Since the C source code was given to us by the teacher, we suspect we've done something wrong in our assembler code.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is our routine:

```
section .text

global mysort

mysort:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp
    sub rsp, 8
    mov r10, rcx    ; r10 -> pointer to array
    mov r11, rdx    ; r11 -> length
; The gaps
    add rsp, 800
    mov r13, 10
    mov [rsp], r13
    mov r13, 4
    mov [rsp+8], r13
    mov r13, 1
    mov [rsp+16], r13
    xor rax, rax             ; l := 0
gaploop:
    mov rbx, [rsp+4*rax]   ; rbx -> current gap value
    mov rcx, rbx             ; rcx -> i
insertionsort_outerloop:
    cmp rcx, r11    ; compare i with n
    jge endouterloop
    mov edx, [r10+4*rcx];edx -> temp
    mov rsi, rcx        ;rsi -> j
insertionsort_innerloop:
    mov rdi, rsi    ;
    sub rdi, rbx    ;rdi -> j-gap
    mov r8d, [r10+4*rdi]
    cmp rsi, rbx    ; compare j with gap
    jl endofloop    ; jump to end of loop if j < gap
    cmp r8d, edx    ; compare a[j-gap] with temp
    jna endofloop   ; jump to end of loop if a[j-gap] not greater than temp
    mov [r10+4*rsi], r8d
    sub rsi, rbx
    jmp insertionsort_innerloop 
endofloop:
    mov [r10+4*rsi], edx        ; a[j] := temp
    inc rcx     ; i++
    jmp insertionsort_outerloop
endouterloop:
    inc rax     ; l++
    cmp rax, 1  ; cmp eax with length of gaps
    jle gaploop
    mov rsp,rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

And the C code:

```c
#define ARRAY_SIZE 32768
void mysort (uint32_t array[], uint32_t len);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int f,n;
    uint32_t array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    uint64_t len;
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s input_file output_file\n", argv[0]);
        exit (0);
    }
    printf("Opening %s\n", argv[1]);
    f = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    printf("Input file opened\n");
    len = read(f, array, ARRAY_SIZE*4);
    printf("File size is %u bytes (%lu numbers)\n", len, len/4);
    close (f);
    printf("Sorting...");
    mysort(array, len>>2);
    printf("done\n");
    printf("Opening %s for writing\n", argv[2]);
    f = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
    printf("File descriptor %d; errno = %d\n", f, errno);
    n = write(f, array, len);
    printf("Written %d bytes; errno = %d\n", n, errno);
    close(f);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: There are two 64-bit ABIs for Intel.  Are you sure your C code and assembly routine match?

Comment: You can check the assembly generated by the compiler for the C code to see how it passes arguments to your function.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be following microsoft calling convention, are you on windows?

Either way, this looks horribly wrong: `add rsp, 800`. Did you maybe mean `sub` to allocate some space? (But you already have a `sub` at the start, so you could just adjust the value there).

If it still doesn't work, use a debugger to step through the code and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: I wasn't on Windows and that's why it wasn't working, I had to use different registers for Linux. Thanks.